# List of items that have been ordered by a specific customer & Listing items ordered in a time period

Tags: sql, list

I've been trying stuff but I'm new to SQL and I was wondering if anyone could help provide a solution to my problem.

1) I'm wanting to show a basic list of items that have been ordered by a particular customer in my database.

2) Listing of all orders that have been ordered during the previous week:

```
SELECT Order.Order_number, Customer.Customer_email, Order.Date
FROM Order
INNER JOIN Customer
ON Order.???? =????;
```

(Need to show dates using BETWEEN statement also, but i'm unclear  on how to)

Just the most basic solutions will do.

Thanks, if anyone can help.

Comment: You said, trying stuff - please show us some stuff rather than expecting complete solutions.

Comment: I have, for example 2)

Comment: post the schema + tag the RDBMS..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Order.Order_number, Customer.Customer_email, Order.Date 
FROM Order
WHERE Order.date BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'
INNER JOIN Customer ON Order
```

Just pop in the dates you need the order to be between. Hard coding isn't the best solution, but it's the easier one. Just remember when you are going to start coding on a bigger scale to always make things dynamic as far as possible other wise you will code yourself into a corner.

I hope the syntax helps you out a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much, and yes I'll take that advice on board, thanks again for your contribution to the second question.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with something along these lines:

```
SELECT Order.Order_number, Customer.Customer_email, Order.Date
FROM Order
INNER JOIN Customer
ON Order.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
WHERE Order.Date BETWEEN @datefrom and @dateto
```

Since you didn't post your table structure this is just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of whats the relationship between order and customer?
I will assume you have a customer ID field and order has customer ID also as a foreign key
so...

```
SELECT 
 Order.Order_number, 
 Customer.Customer_email, 
 Order.Date 
FROM Order INNER JOIN Customer ON Order.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
```

so that sorts out your relationship (note take this with a pinch of salt as you have not provided how your entity's are configured.)

Next you want to look at a date between? ok then Normally when taking user input (assuming again) you need a stored proc.

so

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedureName
@orderdatefrom as datetime,
@orderdatetoo as datetime
AS
SELECT 
 Order.Order_number, 
 Customer.Customer_email, 
 Order.Date 
FROM Order INNER JOIN Customer ON Order.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
WHERE (order.date >= @orderdatefrom  AND order.date <= @orderdatetoo)
ORDER BY order.date asc
```

So the @ paramters are there to provide user input, and you simply use them in your condition clause (please note if you change the join to say, left join, you need to use AND instead of WHERE)

As you havent provided much info, this is all assuming certain things.
hope it helps